# Executing Visual Studio from Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am working on a project to convert a large application (Database, SSIS packages, some class libraries, PowerShell scripts) from building using a batch file to TFS build and possibly deploy. Currently, how the process works is that a Batch file is ran, and some inputs are taken in, which get stored as variables (environment which helps determine which build to kick off), than MSBuild is called, like so

```
MSBUILD BuildAll.proj /t:Clean,Build,Package /p:Configuration=%CONFIGURATION% /fl /flp:Summary;LogFile=%LOGFILE% /fl1 /flp1:ErrorsOnly;LogFile=%ERRORLOGFILE% /tv:4.0
```

The BuildAll.proj is a custom project file that sets some variables, but most importantly (and the part that is failing) executes a command to call Visual Studio to build the solution

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Condition=" '%(Application.Solution)' != '' " Command='"$(DevEnv10InstallDir)Devenv.com" %(Application.Solution) /Rebuild $(Configuration)' />
</Target>
```

Here is the log that gets built out

```
 Target "Build" in project "C:\Source\MBFinancial\Development\Trunk\Source\BuildAll.proj" (entry point):
 Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
 Task "Exec"
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Devenv.com" Application.sln /Rebuild LocalDevelopment
```

When I look at the Build Events, it just hangs there, and the Build Folder on the TFS server is never populated as it should. The build process runs just fine if I run it from the TFS server, running as the TFS Build Account, so I know all the proper installs are on the Build Server, but when I execute through Visual Studio Team Explorer, it hangs. I can provide additional details if needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using devenv.com to build the solution rather than MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a /out switch to devenv.exe (pretty sure you can to devenv.com too), I think you're only looking at teambuild's output and not devenv's, which hopefully will shed light on what's up.
FWIW here's my exec task:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Xxx" Command='"$(VS2010)"\devenv.exe xxx.sln /REBUILD "$(Configuration)|x86" /OUT $(MakeLog) /LOG C:\tmp\ActivityLog.xml' ContinueOnError="false" />
```

I can't remember why I use .exe and an outfile rather than .com.